# Find the generators of $\mathbb{Z}^\times_{18}$ under multiplication.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Find the generators of $\mathbb{Z}^\times_{18}$ under multiplication.

I know how to do it when it's a prime but I don't know how to do it when it's not a prime. Can someone help me please? Thanks.

Comment: How do you find the generators of $\mathbb{Z}^\times_p$ when $p$ is prime?

Answer (score 1):

$(\mathbf Z/18\mathbf Z)^\times=\{\pm 1,\pm 5 \pm 7\}$. It is a group of order $6$ and its generators are the elements with order $6$. It is enough to find which elements $x\ne \pm1$ are such that $x^3=-1$. One checks there's only one generator: $5$.

Answer (score 1):

We have $\mathbb{Z}_{18}^{\times}=\{\overline{1},\overline{5},\overline{7},\overline{11},\overline{13},\overline{17}\}$ and the generators are all the elements of order $6$, which is the order of $\mathbb{Z}_{18}^{\times}$. Since the order of every element divides the order of the group where it belongs (by Lagrange's theorem), the possible orders are 1(only for $\bar{1}$), $2,3$ and $6$. So:

$\overline{5}^2=\overline{25}=\overline{7},~ \overline{5}^3=\overline{35}=\overline{11}$, so the order of $\overline{5}$ is $6$ and $\overline{5}$ is a generator of $\mathbb{Z}_{18}^{\times}$.

You continue that way for the rest of the elements. This is one way (the hard one). Another option is to note that since $\mathbb{Z}_{18}^{\times}$ is cyclic, it's generators are the elements of the form $\overline{5}^k$ of order $6$. Since the order of $\overline{5}^k$ is $\frac{6}{gcd(6,k)}$, the only generators are $\overline{5},~\overline{5}^5=\overline{11}.$

Notice that generators always come in pairs, i.e. if $g$ is a generator then $g^{-1}$ is also a generator.

Answer (score 0):

This group is small enough that you can just brute-force it. Consider each element, and check if it generates the full group.

Answer (score 0):

As others have touched upon, $|(\Bbb Z_{18})^{\times}| = 6$. Since the multiplication (mod $18$) of $\Bbb Z_{18}$ is commutative, this is an *abelian* group of order $6$, and is thus cyclic. For any cyclic group of order $6$, say $G = \langle a\rangle$, we have just two generators, $a,a^{-1} = a^5$. Since the identity $[1]_{18}$ is clearly NOT a generator (it has order $1$), we've got a 40% chance of picking one of the two generators out of the remaining five, just by choosing at random.

Eliminating $[-1]_{18} = [17]_{18}$ straight off the bat is easy, it clearly has order $2 < 6$. Just to be perverse, let's look at $[7]_{18}$. We find that $[7]_{18}^2 = [13]_{18}$, and so $[7]^3 = [1]_{18}$. This shows both $[7]_{18},[13]_{18}$ have order $3$ (because in a cyclic group of order $3$, say $\langle x\rangle$, both $x$ and $x^2$ have order $3$).

The remaining elements, therefore, must have order $6$, so the generators are $[5]_{18},[11]_{18}$.